# Different list item alignment in Explorer vs Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have an ordered list with an unordered list nested within it. The ordered list items provide sequential years and the unordered list items are links to class photos, etc. Dead simple, right?

They display properly in Chrome, Firefox and my old Windows version of Safari, but there is an extra space displayed in Explorer.

Edited Friday, Feb. 17:
Here is an example with all of the html and css. It displays properly in Firefox and Chrome but generates an extra space in IE.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test for StackOverflow</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 background-color: white;
 margin-left: 2%;
 margin-right: 2%;
 font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
 line-height:1.2;
 max-width:100%;
 }

li.year {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: larger;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 0.1em;
 margin: 0.5em;
}
li.year ul {
 font-weight: normal;
 list-style-type: disc;
 font-size: smaller;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ol>
    <li class="year" value="1959">
        <ul>
            <li>First line of text.</li>
            <li>Second line of text.</li>
        </ul>
 
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, preferably as a snippet here in the question?

Comment: I've completely revised the item and have included all code and css.

Comment: @Chaz.D. Where does the space display in IE?

Comment: @Chaz.D.This is terrible! I haven't found any solution yet - attempts to turn margins and paddings off have all failed. In fact, the only thing that works is to turn the inner list into a non-list. That is, make the browser think it's just a block. And then put bullets before the items with the `::before` pseudo-element. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/14jt1j46/1/). Hope this will get you somewhere! (Not posting this as an answer, because this is not a solution, just a workaround.)

Comment: @Chaz.D. I fixed the indenting above and noticed that you are leaving out the last `<li>`. I know that's technically fine, but I wonder if putting it in will help IE? Unless that's just in the example... Also, one thing I've come across with this kind of thing is that there will be some extra white space in your code which a browser might render and cause unexpected results. Could you attempt to run all that code together into a single line with no white space, just to verify that this isn't the issue?

Comment: @JakeParis -- do you mean I left out the last </li>? I just tried that and it made no difference. I also removed all white space from the css and again, made no difference.

Comment: @Mr Lister -- I've been playing with that idea -- pseudo elements, etc. But this isn't a show-stopper for my website as most IE users won't even notice the extra space.

Comment: As a point of interest, I went into Staples yesterday and looked at my website on a new Windows desktop using Edge. Exactly the same extra space was generated for every first line of the <ol><ul> combination. You can see an example in the website at http://www.atikokanhistory.org/#yr1960 . If you look at it in IE, there is extra white space thrown to the right of each year. Other browsers have no extra white apace.

Comment: I want to thank everyone who has scratched their heads over this. I tried the new "fixspace" code suggested, and it fixed most of the items, but it wasn't consistant -- my changing of "float:left; to float:right; caused short lines to float right (duh!) and restoring back to float:left caused the years to be displayed flush right at the right margin of the page.

Comment: So I'll just live with it. This reminds me of the good old days in the last century, when arguing with IBM's tech support about bugs in their code. They were quite scandalized and said "That's not a bug, sir, that's a feature!"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Internet Explorer (and Edge) is allocating the `<li class="year">` it's own line. So before the nested `<ul>` element starts, IE/Edge is printing a single line, in effect a line-break. Not sure why.

In order to fix this for IE (without adversely affected better browsers), you can float the `<ul>` and add a clearfix hack to the `<li class="year">`. I've indicated my styles to fix the issue below with the class `.fixspace`. Try adding and removing that class to see the difference in IE (remember the problem is only visible in IE/Edge):

```css
body {
 background-color: white;
 margin-left: 2%;
 margin-right: 2%;
 font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
 line-height:1.2;
 max-width:100%;
 }

li.year {
 font-weight: bold;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 0.1em;
 margin: 0.5em;
}
li.year ul {
 font-weight: normal;
 list-style-type: disc;
 font-size: smaller;
}

/* These are the added styles:
 */
li.fixspace ul { 
  float: left;
}
li.fixspace:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="year fixspace">
    <ul>
      <li title="Item was added or updated in 2016" class="liyear2016">
        <a id="bryk-northstar-staff-2011-12" href="bryk-northstar-staff-2011-12.htm">North Star School Staff, 2011-12.</a> Surnames: <span class="bold">Bolen, Braun, Burton, Cain, Cameron, Caul, Dunnet, Evans-Duquette, Fairfield, Ferguson, Fraser, Hawkins, Hayes, Labossiere, Makarenko, Myrberg, Niskanen, Ojala, Riding, Thomas.</span> <span class="redline">(Added February 8, 2016)</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Sorry for this very late reply. I haven't looked at this site since February. I tried your css snippet and strangely it floats the year right instead of left. Internet Explorer 8 on Windows XP

Comment: OK, out of curiosity, I changed "float:left" to "float:right" in your css to see what would happen. The year floats LEFT for crying out loud, completely opposite to what's in the css. Firefox also floated it left (floated it left when the css said float:right too). Very strange.

Answer (score -2):

you should use

```
*{margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
```

add it to the head of file css.

Comment: thanks for your reply but this made no difference other than to remove padding and margins outside the boxed area. The blank space is still displayed in Explorer.

Comment: you need reset css for IE